# Reading in Content From URLS in a File

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

I'm trying to get other subset URLs from a main URL. However,as I print to see if I get the content, I noticed that I am only getting the HTML, not the URLs within it.

```
import urllib
file = 'http://example.com'

with urllib.request.urlopen(file) as url:
    collection = url.read().decode('UTF-8')
```

Comment: Is the content being loaded by javascript?

Comment: "url_file" should be "url" ?

Comment: yes, it's being loaded by javascript

Comment: Are you trying to get a pic of the rendered page? The HTML is the contents, if you want more maybe use Selenium or Chrome Headless

Comment: sorry for the bad wording. what i am trying to accomplish is taking a URL and extracting URLs within the main one.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.
You can use beautiful soup library of python and this code should work with python3

```
    import urllib
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    def get_all_urls(url):
        open = urlopen(url)
        url_html = BeautifulSoup(open, 'html.parser')
        for link in url_html.find_all('a'):
            links = str(link.get('href'))
            if links.startswith('http'):
                print(links)
            else:
                print(url + str(links))
    get_all_urls('url.com')
```